# PyMongo cursor - Modify and use value

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor, pymongo

I am encountering difficulties with my PyMongo script:
My documents have a field "used" : "false" or "true".
I want to iterate over the documents whose "use" fields are "false" and use their "friends" field (which is an array of _id values) to add their own _id value to the friends field of every person who is also in the current person's friends field. It should look somewhat like this:

```
"person_id": "Hans",
"used": "false",
"friends": {
    "Hugo",
    "Kunigunde"
}
```

Afterwards, `Hugo` and `Kunigunde` should have `Hans` as entry in their friends list and `used` of `Hans` should be `true`.
My current approach is

```
cursor = db.People.find({"used": "false" })
            for document in cursor:
```

But I don't know how to continue this. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding `Hans` to `Hugo` and `Kunigundes` friendslist:

```
for friend in cursor_pointing_to_Hans['friends']:
    friend_list=db.People.find({'person_id':friend})['friends']
    friend_list.append(cursor_pointing_to_Hans['person_id'])
    db.People.update({'person_id':friend},{'friends':friend_list})
```

For setting `Hans` `used` field to true:

```
db.People.update({'person_id':cursor_pointing_to_Hans['person_id']}, {'used':"true"})
```

Furthermore as you are working in Python I´d suggest to use the boolean python values `True` and `False` instead of the Strings "true" and "false"